# is it possible to implement Java arrays without ever using the special array token [ ]

Tags: java

This is a Java style question.  The brackets empty declare an array reference.  With the 'new' keyword, they instantiate.  Without the 'new' keyword, they index.

```
char[] myArray = new char[100];
output.format("%c\n", myArray[43]);
```

Of these uses of the brackets, the first case is an anomaly since it uses a special token to declare and does not look like a normal Java reserved word or Java identifier and has no number between the brackets.  Is there an alternative that avoids this anomalous case?

Edit: Why might this matter?  Arrays might be faster or use less memory than collections classes.

Comment: That's just the way the grammar/language is. There is `java.lang.reflect.Array`, but I can hardly imagine that is desired ;-)

Comment: I don't think it's an anomaly. It defines a reference variable to an array of chars. If you want to get rid of arrays, use the collections framework (`java.util.List` et al).

Comment: I usually avoid arrays but I did on a certain occasion use a char array because I suspected that any Java collection would be slower and offered far more methods than necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted to, you could do this:

```
Object array = new int[8];
Array.set(array, 3, 5); // like array[3] = 5;
int x = (Integer) Array.get(array, 3); // like x = array[3];
```

This doesn't involve reflection, so purists shouldn't be offended.

Comment: No reflection? :-/ Surely there must be *some* magic, an object typed ... well, Object, is passed in. (Among other things, it also needs to compare the *type* of array passed in and the *type* of value passed in to determine if it needs to unbox the value.) I can't imagine the bytecode emitted is in any way comparable.

Comment: Nope - no reflection. However, if the object passed to `Array.get/set` isn't an array, you get `IllegalArgumentException`. It checks if `object.getClass().isArray()` is `true`.

Comment: @Bohemian I think the static method you are using comes from java.lang.reflect.Array and so it might be using reflection.  This meets the requirements of an answer but unfortunately for me, it uses Object so it probably is not advisable because of type safety.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly anamolous, as @pst pointed out in the comments, because that is how types are named in Java.

However, if you never have to declare a variable of an array type, but you just use array expressions, you can avoid the type expression.  For instance, it is possible to write:

```
Arrays.asList(4, 6, 5, 3, 2).toArray()
```

as in

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class S  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.asList(4, 6, 5, 3, 2).toArray()));
    }
}
```

Also when you write variadic methods in Java, you do not declare the type with the funny empty brackets:

```
public void f(int x...) {
    // x is an int array in here, woohoo
}
```

Not sure whether these examples are useful to you or not, but it does show that yes, you can end up using arrays without `[]`.

Comment: End up using *Lists* created from *Arrays* ;-) However, they are two independent objects -- which may or may not be good -- and modifying the *collection of items contained in one* will not affect the other. (If the items themselves are mutated, that's a different story... I hopefully excluded above :)

Comment: All true, @pst, but it's still fun to try these things out.  I think, though, it is more like arrays created _from_ lists.  Both `toArray()` and variadic parameters are real arrays, which is, I believe, what the OP was interested in.

Comment: They are indeed very hand constructs.

Comment: @RayToal, This answer is good.  This is useful if you need to initialize the array.  If not, then I would suggest `Object thing = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0).toArray();` in order to make it equivalent to the zero initialized array declared with `new int[3]`.